# Python List comprehension when item index is required

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am attempting to write the corresponding list comprehension for the following code snippet.

```
# Initialize data.
queryRelDict = {'1': [1, 2, 3],
                '2': [4, 5, 6],
                '3': [11, 13, 14]}
related_docs_indices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14]

relOrNot = [0] * k
for item in queryRelDict.keys():
    for i in range(len(related_docs_indices)):
        if related_docs_indices[i] + 1 in queryRelDict[item]:
            relOrNot[i] = 1
```

Basically I have a dictionary, where each key has a list as its value. Now my list `relOrNot[i]` needs to be 1, if `ith` element of `related_docs_indices` is in either of the lists in the dictionary.

The desired Output is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I tried the following two variations, but is not able to get the desired output.

```
relOrNot2 = [1 for item in queryRelDict.keys() for i in range(len(related_docs_indices)) if related_docs_indices[i] + 1 in queryRelDict[item]]
```

but the output is

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I also tried

```
relOrNot2 = [1 if related_docs_indices[i] + 1 in queryRelDict[item] else 0 for item in queryRelDict.keys() for i in range(len(related_docs_indices))]
```

Corresponding Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What modification is necessary to get the desired output?

Comment: I can't understand the The desired Output. It's length is not the same as `related_docs_indices`.

Comment: Don't do it - your code is perfectly fine as it is (especially as readability is concerned); a list comprehension would violate [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and the Zen of Python.

Comment: Are you sure that is your desired output?  It's length is 30, but you are iterating three keys over an index of length 11.  Shouldn't the desired result be of length 33?

Comment: unclear what the desired output is

Comment: "Now my list relOrNot[i] needs to be 1, if ith element of related_docs_indices is in either of the lists in the dictionary" ... this is not what you claim your desired output is

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. As Julien points out, your statement of desired output does not match the output that follows - `related_docs_indices` and `relOrNot` should have the same length according your your requirement.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Completely agree. I don't see a point in using list comprehension here only to make it less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if you want an one-liner :)

`relOrNot = [1 if v in set().union(*queryRelDict.values()) else 0 for v in related_docs_indices]`

Answer (score 1):

If your desired output is a list `relOrNot`, where `relOrNot[i]` is 1, if ith element of `related_docs_indices` is in either of the lists in the dictionary `queryRelDict` (then it must have the same length as `related_docs_indices`), then you can do the following:

```
# first create one flat list with all elements of the sublists in the dictionary
flatlist = [i for sublist in queryRelDict.itervalues() for i in sublist]
relOrNot = [1 if i in flatlist else 0 for i in related_docs_indices]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

For each key, you are iterating through the `related_doc_indices` and checking if there is a matching value within the set of values for that key.  For key '1', it would look like this:

```
key 1 values = [1, 2, 3]

related_docs_indices = [
    1, # 1 (match)
    2, # 1 (match)
    3, # 1 (match)
    4, # 0 (no match)
    5, # 0 (no match)
    6, # 0 (no match)
    7, # 0 (no match)
    8, # 0 (no match)
    12, # 0 (no match) 
    13, # 0 (no match)
    14] # 0 (no match)
```

The desired output for this key should thus be:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

One issue that you have is that keys are unordered in dictionaries, so that results of the longer list can vary depending on the random order of the keys.  For example:

```
>>> queryRelDict.keys()
['1', '3', '2']
```

Let's say you first sort the keys, then I believe the desired output should look like this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # key '1'
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # key '2'
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]  # key '3'

keys = queryRelDict.keys()
keys.sort()
>>> [1 if i in queryRelDict.get(item) else 0 
     for item in keys for i in related_docs_indices]
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14] related_doc_indices
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # key '1' values: [1, 2, 3]
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # key '2' values: [4, 5, 6]
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]  # key '3' values: [11, 13, 14] (note 11 is not in related_doc_indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a set with all keys and all values and in your loop just look if the required value is in the set.

```
s = set()
for (k,v) in queryRelDict.items():
    s.add(int(k))# because your keys are string
    s = s | set(v)
map(lambda x:1 if x in s else 0, related_docs_indices)

=>[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```